# "rpmbuild -bb package.spec" configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild

When I build the spec file with `rpmbuild -bb package.spec`, I get this error about needing support for C++ 11

`configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.`

However, when I compile it without rpmbuild, I don't get that.  Also, when I use `mock` to build it, I also do not get any errors.  I don't understand what's different about `rpmbuild -bb`

I have both `clang` and `gcc` installed

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0 (Fedora 10.0.0-1.fc32)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 10.0.1 20200328 (Red Hat 10.0.1-0.11)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ uname -r
5.6.7-300.fc32.x86_64
```

Here's the spec file: https://github.com/dagostinelli/fswatch-packaging

Comment: Going to need to add more context of the error; it seems like `./configure` is being called in some way that isn't finding the compiler properly

Comment: With no clang installed : `cd rpmbuild/ && rpmbuild -bb fswatch.spec .... Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/fswatch-1.14.0-2.fc32.x86_64.rpm` etc. etc. packages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove clang. I don't know why it got installed on my machine and what's the reason for it to exist at all but I just had the same problem -- ANY rpm build failed with configure being unable to find gcc, picking that stupid clang instead and failing.

I went through multiple version updates on this machine using dnf upgrade and the oldest clang remnant I found was from Fedora 28.

Had to build an svn version of gputils (to use gpasm on PIC16F15323 that is still missing in official Fedora pack), tried to build a Fedora 32 package using my existing spec and it failed with "GCC can't create executables".

Removing all clang* (there was leftover clang5.0 and clang6.0 libraries for some reason dated Fedora 29 and up in addition to clang 10 stuff) fixed the problem.